# How to delete one of the persistent volume claim attached to one Storage class

Tags: azure-storage, azure-aks, azure-storage-account, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

I created a 'file share' in the storage account and connected it to my Kubernetes cluster (AKS). I have connected as a dynamic file share following the example from this link:
https://github.com/HoussemDellai/aks-file-share/tree/main/dynamic-file-share.
Thus, I created a Storage Class. And then I made several Persistent Volume Claims in each required namespace.
I added Persistent Volume Claim to my deployment for each application and everything works fine. All my applications in all the necessary namespaces see the shared folder and can write and read to it.
Now I want to remove or detach this storage for one of the namespaces. If I delete one of the Persistent Volume Claims, then the entire file share in the storage account is deleted. But I, for example, need to delete all links and references to this resource in only one namespace. What I should do?
And the second question, after I deleted, for example, all references in the namespace to a file share, after a while if I want to create it again, what steps should I take here?
Once again I will emphasize the essence of the question, the main thing in all this is to remove the link somehow, Persistent Volume Claim or something else to the file share in only one namespac, so that in all the rest all the referring resources and Persistent Volume Claim continue to work correctly with the same 'file share'!

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I think you just need to change the reclaimpolicy of your storageclass from default ( which is Delete) to Retain.

See https://faun.pub/kubernetes-how-to-set-reclaimpolicy-for-persistentvolumeclaim-7eb7d002bb2e for more explanation.